# App hangs when property is included in block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a UIViewController which displays a table of data that is pulled from an online database. I have a singleton manager to handle the pulling of this data **and** provide the data the table needs.

This is an example of how the manager works:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;
...
- (void)refreshDataSource
{
    [AClass fetchInBackgroundWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *objects) {
        self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];
    }
}
...
- (NSArray *)tableViewDataSource
{
    return self.dataArray;
}
```

The view controller requests an update by calling `-refreshDataSource` in `-viewDidLoad` but in the meantime provides its UITableView with cache data from the manager by pointing to -tableViewDataSource.

When the view controller presents itself for the first time, everything is fine. The second time I go to present the same view controller, the app hangs. The network request doesn't fire either.

The only fix I've found is moving my `-refreshDataSource` call to `-viewDidAppear:` instead. But it itches me why this would be happening and discomforts me that something here must be wrong.

If anyone could provide any help or suggestions that would be great!

Comment: I don't see a `retain` in your `@property` declaration of `dataArray`.

Comment: @s.bandara In ARC, strong is the default for objects properties

Comment: That's right, I should have mentioned my project is using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Your question hasn't explained everything, but here are a couple of ideas that might help you.

1) viewDidLoad is only called the first time your view loads. If you switch to a different view, then return to your tableView, refreshDataSource will not be called.

2) viewDidLoad might be firing before an array has been allocated and initialised, so it's nil when you're refreshing the data, whereas viewDidAppear might not have the same problem.

I can't give a more concrete answer without more information. Can you explain "the first time, everything is fine. The second time I go..." more clearly? Step-by-step what you do, if possible.

Comment: Thanks Rowan. The array seems to be initialised in time. To be more detailed about the view appearance, the VC is pushed onto my navigation stack. I pop the VC and push it again, and this is when my app hangs. Each time I push the VC onto the stack, `-viewDidLoad` gets called (as expected).